# Inserting data in database reverse way

Tags: android, sqlite

I have one registration form which is connected to database.When i insert the record the recent record comes first in table.I want recent record to be appeared below the last entered record.
Can you help me out there?

```
long flag = 0;
int id = 1;
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query("tbl_countries", new String[]{"count(*) phone"}, null, null, null, null, null);
while(cursor.moveToNext())
{
    int idFromDatabase = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("phone"));
    if(idFromDatabase != 0)
    {
        id = 1 + idFromDatabase;
    }
}
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
//values.put("ID", id);
values.put("phone", Long.parseLong((phone.getText().toString())));
values.put("fname", fnametxt.getText().toString().trim());
values.put("lname", lnametxt.getText().toString().trim());
if(male.isChecked())
{
    values.put("gender","male");
}
else
values.put("gender", "Female");
values.put("email", emailtxt.getText().toString());
values.put("mainpin",pin1.getText().toString()+pin2.getText().toString()+pin3.getText().toString()+pin4.getText().toString());                  
flag = db.insert("tbl_countries", null, values);
if(flag != -1)
{
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have successful inserted this record into database! "+flag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
    toast.show();
    db.close();
    return;
}
else
{
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error occured when insert this record into database!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
    toast.show();
    db.close();
    return;
}
```

Please Suggest me if anything is wrong in my code.

Comment: If you make your `id` column `AUTOINCREMENT`, you don't need to manually generate it the way you seem to be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What can you do is give id (auto increment) column in your Registration table
and when you query your data at that time get it by ascending order for id column
thats it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with the insertion of the records, but with the retrieval.

Strictly theoretically data in a database doesn't have an order. It is retrieved unsorted, or sorted according to whatever criteria you specify.

In this case you'd want to sort on a date field, or possibly the ID, to get the order you want.

Comment: I saw the records in table by using SQLite Browser.The record which is just now inserted is appear befor than previous inserted record.

Comment: It's not just theory, you know. Once you start deleting rows in the middle, pretty much any database will start inserting out-of-order at some point.

Comment: @tdammers Right, but in the actual file on the disk there's still an order. It might be random (or seemingly so) though. In theory the DB is allowed to return the records in a different order for every query if you don't specify one. That's theory of course, in practice they'll probably use the order of the records on disk.

Comment: @KristofProvost: Not all engines store data on disk, and most that do have some kind of maintenance jobs that do things like defrag or rebuild indexes. Some DBMS's have a 'clustered index', which allows you to force the records to be sorted on disk, but other than that, any insertion or deletion can potentially mess up your ordering.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL standard does not guarantee any particular order for previously inserted records upon retrieval. This means that even though you may be seeing those records in what looks like a predictable order, this may change at any time, without any warning. The DBMS in question may decide to defragment its storage at some point, and reorder records in the progress - this is perfectly legal behavior, and you must be prepared for it. The only way of getting records in a reliable consistent order is if you use (surprise!) an `ORDER BY` clause in your retrieval query. Data in the table does not have a defined ordering, it only gets ordered when you retrieve it.

If you want to show your data in order of insertion, consider using an auto-increment column and order by that (either ascending to list oldest first, or descending for newest first).

**TL;DR: insertion order is meaningless in SQL; if you want your data ordered, use `SELECT ... ORDER BY`.**